# Agent-population state chages in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic, agent, population

I have a problem with a project in AnyLogic:

When it switches from one state to another, a member of my population has to change color.  I was able to set the condition, I set the color change but it changes the color of the whole population. Help me, please!

The condition from state to newbus is `stock>0`. The condition from newbus to state is `stock<0`. The action in state is `testa.setFillColor(lime)`. The action in newbus is `testa.setFillColor(lime)`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your statechart sits on `Main` and not inside the agent type itself, right?

Put the state chart into the agent type that makes up the population and it will work (as long as `testa` is the name of some presentation element like a rectangle within that agent type).

Check some example models as many do this as well, if you are confused.

Comment: Nono, my grafic is inside the agent type. Where are the example models?

Comment: then share more info and screenshots on the details pls. Example models can be found under Help/Example Models/. There is a search as well, can't rememeber the exact ones but there are several

Comment: My problem is to access an individual agent from people population and to change his color. There'is a main, with a connection with tha gent population "bus", in the bus i create two state with a link with condition (stock >0) and when the condiction in true a member of population changes color but when i run, all population changes color.

Comment: You can access individual population members using `main.bus.get(i)` where i is the index of that agent. Check the AnyLogic help searching for "where am I and how do I get to" to learn more about these concepts, they are crucial to master :)